# UICollectionView cells hidden after controllerDidChangeContent

Tags: ios, core-data, uicollectionview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a `UICollectionView` whose `dataSource` is backed by an `NSFetchedResultsController`.

The cells will sometimes hide after a content change happens.  They stay as subviews of the collection view, but `isHidden == true`.  None of my code explicitly hides cells, and a property observer for `isHidden` is never tripped.

HINT: our code does have a bail-out case where it can modify core data in `cellForItem...` or `willDisplayCell`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that there were times when we'd try to construct the cell being requested, fail, and modify CoreData before returning a fallback version of the cell.

`cellForItem` or `willDisplayCell` are running on the main thread, and we were using `performWithBlockAndWait` to modify CoreData.

That was causing a change to the collection view's `dataSource` on the main thread while the collection view was still updating cells.

The simple fix was to use `performWithBlock` instead of `performWithBlockAndWait`.  Now the collection view has a chance to finish updating itself before the data model is changed.

A better fix would be to make such a failure impossible by the time we get to `cellForItem` or `willDisplayCell`.